# Using wp-cron in backpress - problems with wp_remote_post, fsockopen error

Tags: http, wp-remote-request

I'm working on a BackPress project where I need to schedule cron tasks. The cron_uri for BP is stored in options, rather than hardcoded as it is in WP core. I've tried setting the option to **mysite.com/wp-cron.php** (where **wp-cron.php** is essentially a copy of the same file from WordPress, modified to include only the relevant files to my purposes.

The problem is, when this address is called from the [wp_cron()](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/backpress/includes/functions.wp-cron.php.source.html#l168) function, it returns the following fsockopen error:

> fsockopen() **[function.fsockopen]**:
>   unable to connect to :80
>   (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known) in
>   **/home/gad/public_html/backpress/class.wp-http.php**
>   on line 646

I can open the cron uri directly using fsockopen and it doesn't return any error. As best as I can figure out, the problem is somewhere in the HTTP Transport API, maybe in the [WP_http->request()](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/backpress/includes/class.wp-http.php.source.html#l180) function, where BackPress checks the `cron_uri` against the `application_uri` option, to see if the request is a local one or not (and possibly treat the different requests differently?).

Strangely enough, if I just set the `cron_uri` to my home url, it works fine - I can intercept the request based on the GET request and include wp-cron.php before outputting anything.

I'm mainly confused as to why wp_remote_post doesn't seem to work with this file, as it seems to work with most everything else I've tried to do with it.

Comment: HAve you fixed this?I have the same problem and i need this to work both with cUrl and streams, because it's possible that people doesn't have cUrl installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From quick look at source mechanics seem very similar, my first suggestion for WP would be to try and bump HTTP transport to curl (I do it with plugin in WP so no idea about specific code).

curl seems to be considerably more robust for corner cases and it's not WP's first choice.

Comment: I tried searching for the plugin you mentioned, but I can't seem to find it. Whats it called? Link, maybe?

Comment: @goldenapples ah, sorry, slipped me to link - [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/).

Comment: Using curl did work for this case... but I ended up just hacking at the core to force it. Not my best coding moment. I did see the filters that Core Control uses, though, and I'll go back and try and apply those later.